# AWS SDK - Template project fails with timeout

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, iis-express

I'm trying to create a web application to work with the Amazon AWS API. Downloaded the Nuget package and created a project from the AWS Web Project template, ran it, and after a minute it failed with the following error message:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 54.239.39.130:443

The code failed at the last line of the following snippet:

```
IAmazonEC2 ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client();               
var ec2Request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
var ec2Response = ec2Client.DescribeInstances(ec2Request);
```

Now, the weird thing is that it works perfectly from the console, so I assume the issue is related to IIS Express running the application.

Any tip is welcome!

**What I tried:**

- Running VS with the /netonly switch
- Running VS as Administrator
- Changing the .NET Framework to 4.6 / 4.5 / 3.5
- Using AWS SDK v2 and v3

Answer (score 0):

It happened the same to me. 
If you are under a proxy as I am, you may solve it by specifying aws proxy settings in  config section in Web.config

```
<configSections>
    <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core"/>
</configSections>
<aws
    profileName="[yourprofilename]">
    <proxy host="[yourproxyIP/hostname]" port="[yourproxyport]" />
</aws>
```